# How to disable xpack.security.enabled from helm char in elasticsearch deployment on k8s

Tags: elasticsearch, xpack

Is there a way to disable xpack.security.enabled to false from helm chart during elasticsearch deployment on a K8s cluster?

I am getting the below error while reindexing.

```
"error" : {
    "type" : "s_s_l_handshake_exception",
    "reason" : "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "validator_exception",
      "reason" : "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "sun_cert_path_builder_exception",
        "reason" : "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
      }
    }
  }
```

I am not able to edit the elastisearch.yml on the pods as those files are readonly.

Anyway of doing it through helm?

Answer (score 0):

Before installing elasticsearch, create a config file <myconfig.yaml> with

```
esConfig:
  elasticsearch.yml: |
    xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Or any other parameter you want to use in the configuration of ElasticSearch
And use the file in the installation:

helm install es elastic/elasticsearch -f myconfig.yaml

Answer (score -1):

Try to edit the elasticsearch.yml file from the root user.
(sudo vi YOUR_ES_PATH_CONF/elasticsearch.yml)

Change the xpack.security.enabled setting to the ES_PATH_CONF/elasticsearch.yml file.

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
discovery.type: single-node
```

Comment: Tried. Inside the pods I am unable to edit the files. sudo isn't working. Tried changing the permissions of the file as well but it shows the following error : `chmod: changing permissions of '/mnt/elastic-internal/elasticsearch-config/..2020_02_05_08_50_32.365452109/elasticsearch.yml': Read-only file system
`

Comment: let me know your current Operating System?https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250220/debian-sudo-doesnt-work